# Xamarin.Forms - Triggering an IsBusy Binding

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, binding

I have an `IsBusy` binding that can be activated by saying `bool isBusy = true ... or false`.  However,  I have realized that `bool` is the *only* place I can set `IsBusy` to be true/false.

Can I trigger my `IsBusy` binding somewhere other than at `bool`?  I have been trying out `IsBusy = true/false` everywhere and reading tutorials, I'm not sure what I'm doing differently, it does not seem to update my `IsBusy` binding.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Rox;

namespace PreAppStructure
{
    public class RoxViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public RoxViewModel()
        {

        }

        // IsBusy be manually toggled with:  bool isBusy = true/false;

        bool isBusy;

        // Can I toggle it somewhere else?

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public bool IsBusy
        {
            get { return isBusy; }
            set
            {
                isBusy = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsBusy));
            }
        }


        //Property Changes

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, eventArgs);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options to tricker your IsBusy indicator:

- through a command
- through a binding
- through a binding and a converter if your property is not of type bool.

But you need to set IsBusy and not isBusy.